# Membership status rule - restart at 'New'

Tags: civimember

I would like the membership status to revert back to 'New' if someone renews/rejoins once their existing membership is 'Expired' (rather than 'Current').

We're looking at CiviRules for this (likely with a custom action?) but thought I'd ask if anyone has a suggestion on a configuration option that may be more end user friendly that I just can't think of?

Thanks in advance,
Rebecca

Comment: The alternative would be to commence an entirely new/separate membership, so they have the old one still sitting as Expired, and then a second (or subsequent) on that is set as New. If that sounds a helpful approach you need then some googling should find more info about doing this - i can't recall the extension off hand. it may be Membership Extras but i think not

Comment: Thank you! It did cross my mind but we use a customised member dashboard and that doesn't work as I'd like if there's more than one membership (though it at least at the moment informs them to get in touch). Think the rule may do it and shall update post if it does.

Answer (score 2):

We have gone with a CiviRule and created a custom action:

trigger - 'membership is changed'

field value comparison on 'membership status' from (original value) 'expired' to 'current'

The custom action then changes that status immediately to 'new' with a status override for 6 months from the renewal data.